# How to control sound in windows system?

Tags: c++, windows

My software needs to play a sounds to remind someone.

But at that moment, the computer could be playing music or a movie and so on. I want my application to stop all other sound output when it plays its notification.

How can I do that with c++?

Comment: `I want my application to stop all other sound output when it plays its notification` This is an excellent example of "what if two programs tried to do this" that Raymond Chen blogs about.

Answer (score 1):

You mention just the language C++ so I'm assuming you can use MFC (as class library to simplify your work).

But basically you can do:

```
#include <SDL/SDL_mixer.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    setbuf(stdout, 0);
    setbuf(stderr, 0);

    if (Mix_OpenAudio(44100, AUDIO_S16SYS, 2, 4096) != 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Unable to initialize audio: %s\n", Mix_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    Mix_Music *music = Mix_LoadMUS("notification.mp3");
    if (!music) {
        printf("Mix_LoadNotification(\"notification.mp3\"): %s\n", Mix_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    if (Mix_PlayMusic(music, -1)==-1) {
        printf("Mix_PlayNotification: %s\n", Mix_GetError());
        exit(1);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Here you have how to do a more complex work: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/media_player.aspx